# Total variation of $N_t - \lambda t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-process, total-variation

How can I compute the total variation process of the martingale $ \{N_t - \lambda t \}$ under the assumption that $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $\text{var}(N_t-\lambda t)=N_t+\lambda t$.